# Let link follow clippath

Tags: javascript, html, css, clip-path

I am trying to figure out how to display a clickable link only inside the area of the existing clip-path. And also utilize the existing OffsetX value.

```html
<style>
.mouse {
  background-color: aqua;
}
              
.img {
  background-color: black;
}
</style>
            
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="mouse">
    <p id="anchor"></p>
  </div>    
</div>
             
<script>
let main = document.querySelector('.wrap');
let mouse = document.querySelector('.mouse');
let text = "Text link";
let result = text.link("www.stackoverflow.com");
document.getElementById("anchor").innerHTML = result;
 
main.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  mouse.style.clipPath = `circle(15em at ${e.offsetX}px`; 
});
</script>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/snake-py/pen/rNzZOgd I made pen, so do I understand correctly - you want that the link is moving with the offset?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to let the link "stay" inside the circle at the same offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the link to move along with the clip path.

I would do it by so:

```js
mouse.style.clipPath = `circle(5em at ${(e.clientX - main.getBoundingClientRect().x)}px`; 
document.getElementById("anchor").style = "margin-left: " + (e.clientX - main.getBoundingClientRect().x) + "px";
```

This does not utilize the offsetX, but as you move the link, the offsetX would also move along (so it would stay the same), unless you disable pointer events for the link (which might not be intented).